# Remote image not being retrieved in chrome-app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I have a `Chromeapp` which loads a `HTML` file with an `input`. I can put a path into the `input` to a `jpg`, when the form is submited the image is retrieved and loaded into a `canvas` element.

I can also specify a URL to a `jpg` somewhere on the net and the image will be retrieved and loaded too.

This works fines but when packaged as a `Chrome-app`, a remote image doesn't load and theres no errors in extensions page. Any ideas? Local images load fine its only remote images that are not working.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Image renderer",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known restriction of Chrome Apps, and the solutions are well-documented as well. For example, here's the problem and the solution on Google's doc page:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external

Basically, you download the image bits with XMLHttpRequest, get the bits as a blob, form that blob into a data URL, and use that URL in the img element.